# Filter large data set with ordered factors, conditional upon other values in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

my dataframe (bact) has ~4500 rows (bacterial taxa), and 19 useful columns (mostly samples). This is the output of metegenomics data that contains rankID information (ordered factor) and gene matches in multiple sample columns (p'x'), as well as a column with sums of gene matches across taxa (total). I intended to transform to 'long' format after I do some cleaning up of the rows.

*The problem is*: There are many overlapping taxa (higher-level taxa that are unclassified, and lower-level taxa that have a classification (name)) and the goal for downstream data analysis and graphing is to have phylogenetically relevant taxa descriptions associated with the data (in this case gene matches).

*For example*:

```
 rankID             taxon           total    
 0.2.1              Acidobacteria   994577
 0.2.1.1            Acidobacteria   917570
 0.2.1.1.1          11B-2           3
 0.2.1.1.1.1        unclassified    3
 0.2.1.1.1.1.1      unclassified    3
 0.2.1.1.2          AT-s3-28        2975
 0.2.1.1.2.1        unclassified    2975
 0.2.1.1.2.1.1      unclassified    2975
```

I would like to *remove all rows* that have the same value in the 'total' column and are a higher 'rankID' (in this case: 0.2.1.1.1; 0.2.1.1.1.1;0.2.1.1.2.1;0.2.1.1.2.1.1). **Note**: I don't want to remove all 'unclassified' in taxon because at times these are actually necessary to keep.

Here is what I thought might work:

```
bact<- read.csv('cSSU_bacteria_full.csv')
str(bact)
bact$rankID <- factor(bact$rankID, ordered = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

bact %>%
   filter(!(any(order(levels(rankID)) < order(levels(rankID)) & total == total)))
```

The goal is to remove redundant rows, keeping the lowest-level taxon when the totals are equal, therefore removing taxa that explain each other but one is classified (has a name) and the others are not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two components to your `rankID`. The first one is how long the rankID is. For example, the second line has a string length of 7. We can use this to our advantage. According to your data above, the total amount with the highest number of characters is the lowest rank.

The other component is the sum of the numbers in the `rankID`. No rank has both the same character length and same sum of the numbers. Luckily, to do this we only need the string length.

To do this, though, you need to make sure that `rankID` is actually a string and not a factor.

```
bact %>% 
mutate(StringLength = nchar(rankID, type = 'char')) %>%
group_by(total) %>%
filter(StringLength == max(StringLength))
```

This should do the trick.